# How to find out SQLite version using older versions of PHP?

Tags: sqlite, version

Currently I am using PHP 5.2.0 and SQLite 2. Newer versions of PHP have sqlite3::version to detect sqlite version, but for backward compatibility I want to detect version of sqlite on php version < 5.3.0.

I also need to detect if the current sqlite version is lower than 3.7.11, but because I cannot get the number I cannot compare versions.

Comment: did you try `sqlite_libversion`?

Comment: I did not try it because I did not find it. This could be considered as an answer +1